# Copy faces from an object to the same object but in another file

Tags: objects, faces

:) I have several files with objects where I need to have some faces very similar. It would be much easier and faster if I could copy the 64 faces I need equal from the first one into the others (different files), instead of creating them from sratch in each of them.
Is there a way to copy faces from an object in one file to an object in another file?
Thank you!

Comment: Off the top of my head, select the faces in Edit mode, duplicate them with Shift-D then seperate them into a new object with 'P' > Selection. Then name the new object so that you can find it easily, save the file, and in the destination file use File > Append..., select the source file then Object > <Name of selection> to import it. You'll then have to work out how to use those faces in your file, maybe by placing them where you want them and Ctrl-J to join the two objects.

Comment: That actually works great for what I need! You've just saved me a lot of time! Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Excellent! I didn't add it as a full answer as I was just writing down my thoughts and wasn't sure it would be suitable. Don't forget to delete the duplicate object from your old file or you might wonder what the odd object is if you try to render it in future! :^)

Comment: Sure!! Thanks for the advice! :) I am new to blender and still have to learn a lot! :D This was absolutely useful today to make my work much faster! Thanks again! Cheers!!^^